# CircleCI - SDK location not found for Android Studio project

Tags: android, circleci

While attempting to build the project on CircleCI, the following error occurs during the gradle build. What is the cause for this issue? I am running **CircleCI 2.0**.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
>   > SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 18s Exited with code 1

**This is what my config.yml looks like:**

```
# Java Gradle CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-java/ for more details
#
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # - image: circleci/postgres:9.4

    working_directory: ~/repo

    environment:
      # Customize the JVM maximum heap limit
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
      TERM: dumb

    steps:
      - checkout

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run: gradle dependencies

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.m2
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}

      # run tests!
      - run: gradle test
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [sample configuration](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-android/) provided by CircleCI for Android, which handles the SDK issue you're running into. I'm not sure why they don't show this option when setting up a new Project to follow.

Basically when you set up a new project to follow on CircleCI, you probably chose the Gradle (Java) option. This doesn't specifically target Android, so that's why it's complaining about a missing SDK.

The sample configuration linked above looks like the below (the most important part being the docker image specified, the CircleCI doc has a good explanation of what each line is doing):

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/code
    docker:
      - image: circleci/android:api-25-alpha
    environment:
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  
"app/build.gradle" }}
      - run:
          name: Download Dependencies
          command: ./gradlew androidDependencies
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  
"app/build.gradle" }}
      - run:
          name: Run Tests
          command: ./gradlew lint test
      - store_artifacts:
          path: app/build/reports
          destination: reports
      - store_test_results:
          path: app/build/test-results
```

Hope you get building OK soon!

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me.
I had to uncomment also the permissions part in the file:

`#      - run:
#         name: Chmod permissions #if permission for Gradlew Dependencies fail, use this. 
#         command: sudo chmod +x ./gradlew`

Comment: For Me, I am getting this error,                                              
Configuration errors: 2 errors occurred:

* Error parsing config file: yaml: line 17: could not find expected ':'
* Cannot find a job named `build` to run in the `jobs:` section of your configuration file.
If you expected a workflow to run, check your config contains a top-level key called 'workflows:'

Comment: Hey @SreedevR, this sounds like your config.yml file might be incorrect. Do you have a link to it so I can take a look?

Answer (score 2):

I used this and it worked for me.
Initially had an indexing issue all along. The code wasn't indexed properly. This could be someone's issue

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
working_directory: ~/code
docker:
  - image: circleci/android:api-25-alpha
environment:
  JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
steps:
  - checkout
  - restore_cache:
      key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
  - run:
     name: Chmod permissions #if permission for Gradlew Dependencies fail, use this.
     command: sudo chmod +x ./gradlew
  - run:
      name: Download Dependencies
      command: ./gradlew androidDependencies
  - save_cache:
      paths:
        - ~/.gradle
      key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
  - run:
      name: Run Tests
      command: ./gradlew lint test
  - store_artifacts:
      path: app/build/reports
      destination: reports
  - store_test_results:
      path: app/build/test-results
```